# Why do I get "error: reference to 'align_val_t' is ambiguous" with Intel's C++ 2022 compiler when using std::inplace_merge?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, icc, ambiguity

When I try to compile this with the Intel C++ Compiler 2022 toolset for Visual Studio 2022:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    std::inplace_merge(&x, &x, &x);
}
```

I get:

```
VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\xmemory(1429,48): error : reference to 'align_val_t' is ambiguous
                _Pbuf = ::operator new (_Size, align_val_t{alignof(_Ty)}, nothrow);
                                               ^
VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\algorithm(7152,57): note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Optimistic_temporary_buffer<int>::_Optimistic_temporary_buffer<long long>' requested here
    _Optimistic_temporary_buffer<_Iter_value_t<_BidIt>> _Temp_buf{(_STD min)(_Count1, _Count2)};
                                                        ^
VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\algorithm(7160,10): note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::inplace_merge<int *, std::less<>>' requested here
    _STD inplace_merge(_First, _Mid, _Last, less<>{});
         ^
Temp.cpp(6,7): note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::inplace_merge<int *>' requested here
        std::inplace_merge(&x, &x, &x);
             ^
VC\14.34.31933\include\vcruntime_new.h(27,16): note: candidate found by name lookup is 'std::align_val_t'
    enum class align_val_t : size_t {};
               ^
note: candidate found by name lookup is 'std::align_val_t'
```

I tried digging through the STL sources, but I can't find where the ambiguity is.

Why does this error occur? And how do I get around it?

Comment: Is that all there is as output? It says that the correct `std::align_val_t` was found, but it doesn't say with what it is ambiguous.

Comment: @user17732522: I missed 3 lines (there's some confusing line interleaving I can't make sense of that I had to fix when pasting), but those only refer to 1 location. There's no second definition I can see that's ambiguous... unless it's defined internally inside the compiler or something? And funny enough I actually get the error if do `#include <memory_resource>` `int main() { }` as well.

Comment: @user17732522: Actually I think that's it... there are multiple internal compiler definitions. And the errors even occurs if you refer to it without including any headers!

Comment: Well, that sounds like something is very wrong. Unfortunately I don't have a setup to try to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, but it seems to be **a bug with precompiled headers**. This occurs even if the precompiled header files are empty.

Avoiding precompiled headers seems to avoid the issue.

If anyone has a better workaround or more details, please do post it.